# rdlc pragmatically change chart scale from linear to log

Tags: rdlc

This may be a silly question, but...

Is it possible to problematically set the chart scale on either axis on an rdlc report chart to either log(x) or linear, without having to parse the xml?
Maybe through a property, or an expression? Or bind it to a value in one of the datasets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do in this cases is to create a new report parameter, that can be set from your code. 
Than you just have to assign the parameter to the **LogBase** property, open the dropdown and select expression. from there you select parameters and the parameter you whant to set to the poperty.

[image]